# Navigation relative spacing

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I have a number of list items in an unordered list that will be used as horizontal navigation. The first and last items (are buttons) get floated left and right but then there is a kind of title (Admission Process) which is centered then the button set (Back/Next) need to be about 75% to the right in this nav list.

Is it best to use a relative value like %, ems I believe? It just needs to be flexible and responsive. I did not add the CSS as it would only probably confuse the issue.

```
<ul id="form-fill-nav" class="clearfix">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" class="btn-nav-1">Selected Forms</a></li>
      <li>Admissions Process</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="btn-nav-1">Back</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="btn-nav-1">Next</a></li>
      <li class="f-right"><a href="#" class="btn-nav-1">22</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS and make a fiddle

Comment: Why would adding the CSS confuse the issue? We need so see what you've already tried / how you've currently set it out to build on that

Comment: sure - http://jsfiddle.net/doug234/qR7eT/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the context to determine the solution:

- Percentage based values are controlled by the relative box sizing
- `em/ex/ch/rem` based values are controlled by relative font sizing
- `vw/vh/vmin/vmax` based values are controlled by relative viewport(window) sizing

**References**

- [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3: Relative Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths)